# What is the best open source automated trading platform or options?

Tags: programming, futures, algorithmic-trading, python

[image]

I would like a custom C++ Automated Trading Platform for Futures like Multicharts, or similar automated trading platform that I can put on my servers so its secure and fast.

I have found this so far, http://quantlib.org/index.shtml

I understand the Hedge Funds build their own, but what's available open source?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: https://lean.quantconnect.com/docs#topic1.html   - is this the best option at the moment ?